# MainWindow.xib and iPhone 5 (4-inch display)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have an universal App, and am trying to get it ready for the iPhone 5.
However, I am running into an issue where the window is not sized correctly. This has probably to do with my setup of the MainWindow.xib, and probably has worked until now, possibly as there was only one size.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
viewController = [[DORootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil];
[self.window setRootViewController:[viewController autorelease]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have an UIView (with children). This is connected to the View of the 'rootViewController' (an UIViewController) which is set as the rootViewController of the window. This all works fine so far, but on the 4" screen I have a problem with my Navigation Controller and the location on the screen. This navigation controller is added to the rootViewController, as the rootViewController has a background which is used in the whole app.

```
[self setNavigationController:[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuView] autorelease]];
[[[self navigationController] view] setOpaque:YES]; 
[[self view] addSubview:[_navigationController view]];
```

I read people has similar issues, and that it is fixed by having a Window in the MainWindow.xib. I tried that, and it fixes the NavigationController issue, but introduces an issue where the App crashes when I show a movie with [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated]; I assume because the connected window is not a view.

It seems to me that the navigation controller is not added properly to the bounds of the window. But why would this be? The result is unpredictable, sometime is seems fine, sometime there is a horizontal offset, both on iOS 5 and iOS 6 (in the simulator).

Anybody any suggestions.

[image: Toolbar in middle screen on 3.5"]

[image: Toolbar and status bar a bit too low on 4"]

[EDIT: updated with more detail and screenshots with the bars on the wrong locations]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
[[self view] addSubview:[_navigationController view]];
```

with:

```
[self presentModalViewController:_navigationController animated:NO];
```